# codes in onClickListener can't be executed

Tags: android

I'm experiencing problem with the following code, I created two buttons with onClickListener added.

It works fine for the Button -- btnAbout, I'm trying to use another way to handle btnIntro, instead of by using findViewById(...) method, but the statement will not be executed when I click btnIntro.

Why does this happen?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private final String TAG = "tag";
    private Button btnIntro;
    private Button btnAbout;
    private View layoutView;
    private ViewWrapper wrapper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
        if (btnIntro == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
            layoutView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.main, null, false);
            wrapper = new ViewWrapper(layoutView);
            layoutView.setTag(wrapper);

        } else {
            wrapper = (ViewWrapper) layoutView.getTag();
        }

        btnIntro = wrapper.getButton();
        Log.e(TAG, Integer.toHexString(layoutView.getId()) + "");
        Log.e(TAG, btnIntro.getText().toString());

        btnIntro.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "static");
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "btnIntro clicked");
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "btnIntro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }
        });

        btnAbout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "btnAbout clicked");
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "about", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    class ViewWrapper {
        View base;
        Button btn1;

        ViewWrapper(View base) {
            this.base = base;
        }

        Button getButton() {
            if (btn1 == null) {
                btn1 = (Button) base.findViewById(R.id.btnIntro);
                Log.e(TAG, btn1.getText().toString());
            }
            return btn1;
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/MAIN_LAYOUT_XML"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="30dip">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test" />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnIntro"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="btnIntro" />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="btnAbout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please explain what you stand to gain by not using the findViewById method.  Also, since layoutView is defined as a type View, the ViewWrapper class should extend View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you use to different content views to obtain buttons, one is created when you invoke setContentView() and second you create by invoking inflator.infate(). Thus buttons you get are placed in different content views (only one of which is shown - that created by setContentView). Try that instead:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
    layoutView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.main, null, false);
    setContentView(layoutView); 
    //..anything you need..
}
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, it works fine now, I learnt a lot from it. :-)